# How to make a SQL Server 2017 local database from C# code in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017

I am trying to write a console game in C#, however, I am running into trouble trying to generate my database for information on the characters, and stage.

My questions are: how do I

1. Create a database file from C# code?
2. Connect to that database after it is been created?
3. And how to add tables to that database from C# code?

I was thinking that I could use fileinfo and filestream classes to make the `.mdf` file, but I would rather be safe by asking you guys.

Comment: Would recommend adding a SSDT project (you will need to add the SSDT package to VS) and then you can do a "Schema Compare" operation to deploy changes to your database. This will save you writing custom applications to deploy your SQL changes and also adds your database to your solution so you can track it.

Comment: I would really want to see the code how you create working mdf + transaction log file from scratch. It will be very interesting.

Comment: @lad2025 you can find the source code at GitHub: https://github.com/shadowlynch/TheWarForWesteros-P1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.net for c# has a library for this, the using statement has to be activated manually though. If you click project in visual studio and click add reference and go to the extras. Mysql.data should have everything you need. And you can connect to the data base by just making a string out of the command. But connect to the database first.

Comment: This does not address the questions being asked!